# Using C++ bindings with GObject Introspection

Tags: c++, linux, gnome, gobject, gobject-introspection

I decided I want to use the [Goffice](http://developer.gnome.org/goffice/unstable/goffice-0.10-Gettings-Started-with-GOffice.html) library in my project. But I write it in C++, so I prefer to have a C++ class interface, just like I use gtkmm and not GTK+ directly.

The documentation (see link above) says I can use GObject Introspection. So I started reading anout it. I read and read and read, and I just couldn't understand how to use any binding of GOffice. I looked for a goffice gi-repository/typelib file on my system, and in the list of files installed by PackageKit. Found nothing. I checked in PackageKit if goffice or goffice-devel packages depend on the gobject introspection package. Maybe they depend indirectly, but they don't depend on it directly (otherwise I'd see it on the list).

I tried and tried, but I couldn't find a resource which could simply explain how to take a library written in GObject, such as GOffice, and use it on another language, e.g. Python, or in my case C++. Of course, I can use the C functions directly, but the point is that I want to have an interface similar to gtkmm.

(I use GNU/Linux, writing a desktop application with gtkmm and GNU build system, goffice version 0.10)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently no GObject Introspection tool for C++.  You can see a list of users at https://live.gnome.org/GObjectIntrospection/Users.

Based on [one of GOffice's automake files](http://git.gnome.org/browse/goffice/tree/goffice/Makefile.am#n608), the GIR name GOffice is GOffice-0.10, so you should expect `$(pkg-config --variable=girdir gobject-introspection-1.0)/GOffice-0.10.gir` and `$(pkg-config --variable=typelibdir gobject-introspection-1.0)/GOffice-0.10.typelib`, but it's possible your distribution's packages don't include those files, in which case you might want to consider filing a bug.

As for documentation on how to use GObject Introspection for Python, you should check out the [PyGObject site](https://live.gnome.org/PyGObject).  They link to the [The Python GTK+ 3 Tutorial](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), which should help you get a feel for how to use PyGObject.  As for other languages, the documentation will vary depending on the language and implementation.

Answer (score 1):

gtkmm, glibmm, and other -mm libraries currently still use the gmmproc tool to generate bindings for GObject-based libraries. This tool is older than GObject Introspection (GI is considered stable from GTK+ 3) and requires manual work on writing headers with special macros which will be used by the tool to generate C++ source code. For more details and a how-to see [Wrapping C Libraries with gmmproc](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/chapter-wrapping-c-libraries.html.en).

As for automatic C++ binding generation using GObject Introspection, I've found only one [WIP](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtkmm-list/2013-November/msg00015.html): [gi-mm](https://github.com/juanrgar/gi-mm).

Alternatively there are [GObject Consume](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GObjectIntrospection/GObjectConsume) and [Smoke-GObject](https://launchpad.net/smoke-gobject) which both can be used to integrate GObjects with C++ through Qt framework.

Answer (score 1):

[cppgir](https://gitlab.com/mnauw/cppgir) is GObject-Introspection C++ binding wrapper generator (also it is listed [here](https://gi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users.html)).

It is lightweight (straight binding), optionally it can be used inline (header-only), therefore the program can directly link to any GObject-based library (GTK, GStreamer, etc).

You can read more information from [README](https://gitlab.com/mnauw/cppgir/blob/master/README.md) and [documentation](https://gitlab.com/mnauw/cppgir/blob/master/docs/cppgir.md).